# What is "Found" referring to in the title of Margaret Peterson Haddix's book?

Tags: title-explanation, the-missing

In the book *Found*, Jonah finds out that he isn't who he thought he was. In fact, he's not from the modern times at all. The people from the future are fighting over him and the other kids like him, but they knew where/when they were.

What is being referred to in the title of *Found*? What was it that was found?